# how to solve at com.example.dbdemo.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)?

Tags: android, android-studio

Please help me out. I have tried everything but am unable to solve this. The app keeps crashing Because of activity main:61 what is wrong with the code?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dbdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    Button btnLogin;
    TextView tvRegister;
    EditText edtEmail,edtPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        tvRegister = findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
        edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
         edtPassword= findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

         SharedPreferenceConfig sp = new SharedPreferenceConfig(getApplicationContext());

         if(sp.readLoginStatus()){
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
         }

       btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               String uname = edtEmail.getText().toString();
               String upass = edtPassword.getText().toString();

               if(uname.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.uname))
               && upass.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.upass))){

                   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
               }
               else {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   edtEmail.setText("");
                   edtPassword.setText("");
               }

           }
       });

         tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent int1 = new Intent(  MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(int1);
             }
         });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml for ActivityMain.java
**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3C3C3C"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email_id"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#D6B5B5"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.417"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.425"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.393"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegister"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="@string/register_yourself"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.912"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.051" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.603" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is RegistrationActivity that is intended to show when I click on on Registr yourself

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dbdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    Button btnRegister;
    EditText edtEmail2 , edtPassword2 , edtPassword3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        edtEmail2 = findViewById(R.id.edtEmail2);
        edtPassword2= findViewById(R.id.edtpassword2);
        edtPassword3= findViewById(R.id.edtPassword3);

        SharedPreferenceConfig sp = new SharedPreferenceConfig(RegistrationActivity.this);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String uname2 = edtEmail2.getText().toString();
                String upass2 = edtPassword2.getText().toString();
                String upass3 = edtPassword3.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_register.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#373737">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail2"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_emailn_id"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.471"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.142"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtpassword2"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.663" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword3"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/reenter_password"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.457"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.467"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It shows that errors in MainActivity:61 but I can't find it
**Error**

at com.example.dbdemo.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)

Comment: Did you registered the RegistrationActivity class in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this error

> Unable to find explicit activity class {.RegistrationActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

then add this in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"/>
```

under the application tag `<Application>`